# LateInitializationError: Field '_youtubePlayerController@341268173' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using youtubePlayer for showing yotube videos in my app but I got error like "LateInitializationError: Field '_youtubePlayerController@341268173' has not been initialized."

Following are my code:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mahuva_azadari/Models/LinkModel.dart';
import 'package:youtube_player_flutter/youtube_player_flutter.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import '../Models/Hexa color.dart';

class LiveProgram extends StatefulWidget {
  const LiveProgram({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LiveProgram> createState() => _LiveProgramState();
}

class _LiveProgramState extends State<LiveProgram> {


  late YoutubePlayerController _youtubePlayerController;


  Future<LinkModel> getAllLinks() async {
    var url = "https://aeliya.000webhostapp.com/MajlisLinks.php";
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var jsondata = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
   

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return LinkModel.fromJson(jsondata);
    } else {
      return LinkModel.fromJson(jsondata);
    }
  }

  @override
  void deactive() {
    _youtubePlayerController.pause();
    super.deactivate();
    print("deactivate");
  }

  @override
  void dipose() {
    _youtubePlayerController.dispose();
    print("dispose");
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return YoutubePlayerBuilder(
      player: YoutubePlayer(
        controller: _youtubePlayerController,
      ),
      builder: (context,player){
        return SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Live Program",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 25
              ),),
              centerTitle: true,
              backgroundColor: Color(hexColors('006064')),
            ),
            body: FutureBuilder<LinkModel>(
              future: getAllLinks(),
              builder: (context, snapshot){
                if(snapshot.hasData){
                  return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data!.data!.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index){
                        var allItem = snapshot.data!.data![index];
                        return Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          child: Card(
                            color: Color(hexColors("00BCD4")),
                            elevation: 6,
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                YoutubePlayer(
                                  controller: _youtubePlayerController = YoutubePlayerController(
                                    initialVideoId: YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(allItem.link!).toString(),
                                    flags: YoutubePlayerFlags(
                                      autoPlay: false,
                                    ),
                                  )..addListener(() {
                                    if(mounted){
                                      setState(() {});
                                    }
                                  }),
                                  showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 10,),
                                Text(_youtubePlayerController.metadata.title.isEmpty? 'Loading Title.....' :
                                "Title: " +_youtubePlayerController.metadata.title,
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                                ),
                                Text("City : ${allItem.city!}"),
                                Text("City : ${allItem.postDateTime!}")

                              ],
                            ),

                          ),
                        );
                      });
                }else{
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

change in variable initialization:-

```
YoutubePlayerController? _youtubePlayerController;
```

I tried to solve this issue removing "late" and write "?", Then it's breaking all my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just haven't instantiated your `_youtubePlayerController`.

As your widget is a `Stateful Widget`, you should add an `initState()` method:

```
@override
void initState() {
    _youtubePlayerController = YoutubePlayerController();
    super.initState();
}
```

Comment: sir, its work but one problem, when do full screen of video then video will autometically next and at the last video of list its shows error "The request contains an invalid parameter value".                    in initstate i write this code _youtubePlayerController = YoutubePlayerController(initialVideoId: ''); as well as this error also occur "updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame."